# Unable to render template

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to send a form html as a json response.  The problem I am having is that ZF2 can not find the forms template file.  I get the error

> Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "admin/categories/form.phtml"; resolver could not resolve to a file

In my controller I have

```php
if (!is_null($form)) {
    $renderer = new PhpRenderer;
    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
    $viewModel->form = $form;
    $viewModel->category = $category;
    $viewModel->setTemplate('admin/categories/form.phtml');
    $form = $renderer->render($viewModel);
}
```

The form.phtml file exists but as I said ZF2 can't find it.  In my module_config.php I have

```php
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions' => true,
    'doctype' => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template' => 'error/404',
    'exception_template' => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'admin/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'error/404' => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'admin' => __DIR__ . '/../view'
    ),
),
```

Does anyone know why ZF can not find my template file?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the full path to the form template?

Comment: \module\Admin\view\admin\categories

Comment: Try setting "admin/categories/form" as template key without the .phtml path. This is how ZF2 maps by convention.

Comment: Hi Bram, thanks for your response, unfortunately this did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what was happening.  The PhpRenderer did not have the paths from the module_config file.  I had to get the PhpRenderer from the service manager.

```
$renderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewmanager')->getRenderer();
```

Once I did this the template was located and rendered fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```or-tag-here
'template_path_stack' => array(
    'admin' => __DIR__ . '/../view'
)
```

with

```or-tag-here
'template_path_stack' => array(
    'admin' => __DIR__ . '/../view/admin'
)
```

or add

```or-tag-here
'template_path_stack' => array(
    'admin' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    __DIR__ . '/../view'
)
```